# Python os.walk returns weirdly formatted root directory

Tags: python, directory, os.walk, os.path

I've written a program which uses tkinter's askdirectory to get a folder and then convert all images into another format. But I've noticed something weird.

The first step the program does is ask for a directory and then use `os.walk` to create a filelist, which the converter (in this case PILLOW for most images and psd-tools for photoshop images) then takes. This code looks something like this:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import os

path = askdirectory(title='Select Folder')

all_files=[]
for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
        all_files.append(os.path.join(root, f))

convert(all_files) #not important here
```

I've written a couple of little scripts that deal with files and paths, so I know how annoying this can be and how allergic some modules react to specific formats for paths. So, when I copy/paste a path into a script, i usually write `path = r"path i copied from file explorer"` and everything beyond that only happens with `os.path.join()`, which has worked perfectly until now.

I noticed strange filepaths in my error messages that claimed it couldn't find a file. So I printed my file lists out:

```
for line in all_files:
    print(line)
```

And i got this:

```
G:/Downloads/New folder (2)\file1.png
G:/Downloads/New folder (2)\file2.png
G:/Downloads/New folder (2)\file3.png
G:/Downloads/New folder (2)\file4.png
...
```

It seems like tkinter formats the string weirdly (one forward slash instead of two backward slashes, which is the case when i copy/paste a dir into a rawString). And os.path.join() cannot understand tkinter paths properly as a result.

But what I don't understand is why it's happening here. Because as far as I see it, `os.path.join` joins not the input path by tkinter with a filename, but it joins the `root` provided by `os.walk`, which *should* be in a format os.path.join understands, because I never had any problems with it before this.

So my question would either be "How can I reformat the tkinter string, so that it gets properly understood as a directory path by `os.path.join` and `os.walk`?" or "Why does `os.walk` behave like this here and put the wrongly formatted directoy into the `root` variable?"

(I know i could *probably* just type `path = path.replace("/", "\")`, but A) i am not sure if there would be other subtle differences and B) i really am curious *why* this imo weird thing it happening, so I don't make a similar mistake again)

EDIT (SOLUTION): Thanks to chepners comment, I was able to fix it (they didn't make a proper 'answer', hence why I'm adding this here, so someone with a similar problem doesn't miss the solution). Replacing the line `all_files.append(os.path.join(root, f))` by `all_files.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(root, f)))` solved it, since normpath can handle a mixture of `/` and `\`. The reason for this can he read in chepners comments, I'm not adding them here.

Comment: It's not `tkinter`. `root` is a string with containing a "normalized" path, using `/` as the separator. But `os.path.join` uses the value of `os.sep`, which for you is a single backslash. That's what results in a mix of separators in your final directory string.

Comment: One possibility is to use `os.path.normcase` or `os.path.normpath`, which will convert all `/` to ``\``.

Comment: `pathlib` might(?) always use `/`, even on Windows. (I don't have a Windows box, so I can't test or verify.)

Comment: @chepner Yes it does. And it accepts a mixture of the 2.

Comment: Ok, I think `norm{case,path}` is probably your best bet, but I am probably not the person to assert that in an answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot chepner! I used normpath(join(root, file)), which you suggested. This works perfectly!